# How to configure Doctrine file mapping driver in ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' with message
>   'File mapping drivers must have a valid directory path, however the
>   given path [path/to/my/entities] seems to be incorrect

and i have this in my module.config.php:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        // defines an annotation driver with two paths, and names it `my_annotation_driver`
        'my_annotation_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../src/Realez/Entity',
                'another/path'
            ),
        ),

        // default metadata driver, aggregates all other drivers into a single one.
        // Override `orm_default` only if you know what you're doing
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                // register `my_annotation_driver` for any entity under namespace `My\Namespace`
                'Realez/Entity' => 'my_annotation_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it by creating an empty `Entity` directory in the location where doctrine expect me to store my entities. All you have to do is create in following location an empty `Entity` directory:  `__DIR__ . '/../src/Realez/Entity'`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your module.config.php file.

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__.'_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                     __NAMESPACE__'\Entity' =>  __NAMESPACE__.'_driver'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),                 
);
```

Comment: this is exactly what I have in my module.config.php file and I'm still getting the same error as the OP

Comment: @Ronak: Please change   
                   __NAMESPACE__'\Entity' =>  __NAMESPACE__.'_driver'
with 
                   __NAMESPACE__.'\Entity' =>  __NAMESPACE__.'_driver'

Answer (score 1):

```
**File mapping drivers must have a valid directory path, however the given path [path/to/my/entities]**
```

this mean you don't have an **Entity** folder at that directory

You just need to create one at that location

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `paths` are correct.

```
           __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
                'class' => AnnotationDriver::class,
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/Entity/'], 
// or:                'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/Entity/'.__NAMESPACE__.'/Entity']

            ],
            'orm_default' => [
                'drivers' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ]
            ],
```

Also you may try clearing metadata cache with doctrine command line tool:

```
./doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:metadata
```